# Kotlin/JS NPE Source Reference

Tags: javascript, kotlin, exception, kotlin-js

I have a Kotlin/JS project that is throwing a null pointer exception, but I can't figure out where it is coming from. The source map in the browser references `exceptionUtils.kt?24ab` which is a generic wrapper for the javascript error:

```
@JsName("throwNPE")
internal fun throwNPE(message: String) {
    throw NullPointerException(message)
}
```

The stack trace for the error shown in the javascript console is, likewise, referencing the javascript bridging code, not my actual Kotlin source:

> "NullPointerException
>
> at Object.captureStack (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:38592:15)
>
> at NullPointerException.Exception [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:38925:14)
>
> at NullPointerException.RuntimeException [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:38951:17)
>
> at RuntimeException_init_0 (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:38962:24)
>
> at new NullPointerException (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:39071:7)
>
> at Object.throwNPE (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:42775:13)
>
> at Kotlin.ensureNotNull (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/kotlin.js:748:35)
>
> at main (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/my-app.js:68:27)
>
> at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/my-app.js:431:3)
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./kotlin-dce-dev/my-app.js:5:35)"

How can I trace this back to the actual Kotlin source for the exception?

Comment: this youtrack issue seems relevant: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39447